# JS Validation Function to for compulsive Alphanumeric & Special Characters Input Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsvalidation

I want to validate an input field **input** or **textarea** with a **COMPULSIVE Alphanumeric requirement**

Conditions -

- It should compulsorily have Numbers as well as Alphabets
- It should allow only these Special Characters **, / - ( ) # .** (namely *** Space, Comma, Forward Slash, Hyphen, Hash, Round Brackets, Dot***)
- It should be of minimum length (assume 10). The length here refers to the combined length of all inputs.

Please keep in mind it is compulsive validation for an address field

The input field shall be set with **class name as ".address"**

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="address_1" class="address">
<input type="text" id="address_2" class="address">
<div class="banner-message">

</div>
<div class="match-message">

</div>
```

jQuery/JS

```
$(".address").keyup(function()
{

address_1 = $("#address_1").val();
address_2 = $("#address_2").val();

full_address = address_1.concat(address_2);
// alert(address);

ADDRESS_REGEX = /^(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])[a-z\d,.()&"##\s-]{10,}$/gi;

//$(".match-message").html(ADDRESS_REGEX.test(full_address));
$(".match-message").html(full_address); // Just to check the combined value from all inputs

if(ADDRESS_REGEX.test(full_address)==true)
{
$(".banner-message").html("Your address is perfect!");
}
else
{
$(".banner-message").html("Please input full address");
}


});
```

Check my [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alphamike/xtvqp0ab/4/)

Comment: Anything you tried to solve your problem ? if yes post that too along with question

Comment: @CodeManiac I've tried this http://jsfiddle.net/uvg5obzx/1/

Answer (score 3):

You should use `test` when you want to just test whether it follows the pattern or not instead of `match`, `test` returns a boolean value whereas match returns an array of matched values.

You can use this pattern

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d,.()#\s-]{10,}$
```

[image]

```js
let addresses = ["hello12312","hellohello","hello-ajd-ajdnajdnasa123","hellohahahahaha-128282()#,.","a 215469874651569847"]

addresses.forEach(address =>{
  let isFine = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d,.()#\s-]{10,}$/i.test(address)
  console.log(address, isFine)
})
```

Comment: @Alpha can elaborate which condition isn't met ?

Comment: @Alpha did you checked the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/s87gyewo/) i linked in answer, isn't it what you're after ?

Comment: @Alpha but it has a space and in your question you aren't allowing space, i don't see anywhere it mentioned to allow space

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the usage of **g**  (global) in the regex

Correct

```
ADDRESS_REGEX = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d,.&"()##\s-]{30,}$/i;
```

Comment: What is the use of `##` inside character class ,second `#` is redundant. in question you ask for minimum length to be 10 and now you post a answer with length 30,  `& " ` weren't specified to be included allowed special characters,